# Accessing OS environment variables from Jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

Is it possible to access a OS environment variable directly from a Jinja2 template?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you can create a filter and use the filter. What do want to do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Following @Renier's pointer about custom filters in the comments, I figured out a possible solution.

Define a [custom filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#writing-filters):

```
def env_override(value, key):
  return os.getenv(key, value)
```

Install the filter in the environment:

```
env.filters['env_override'] = env_override
```

Use the filter as follows:

```
"test" : {{ "default" | env_override('CUSTOM') }}
```

Where the appropriate environment variable can be set as:

```
export CUSTOM=some_value
```

If the environment variable is set the output will be:

```
"test" : some_value
```

Otherwise:

```
"test" : default
```

Comment: Perfect. That is just the best. Exactly my use case, and the syntax looks so nice.

Answer (score 12):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27984610/1070890) works beautifully but you can still get rid of the useless use of cat and compress it to a single statement:

```sh
python -c 'import os
import sys
import jinja2
sys.stdout.write(
    jinja2.Template(sys.stdin.read()
).render(env=os.environ))' <$CONFIGTEMPLATE >$CONFIGFILE
```

P.S.: Stack Overflow does not allow formatted code in comments. Therefore I had to post this as a separate answer instead of commenting on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27984610/1070890.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you can access environment variables like so:

```
{{ env['XMPP_DOMAIN'] or "localhost" }}
```

This is from an example in a config file that I saw recently for a [Docker deployment of ejabberd](https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-ejabberd).

```
hosts:
  - "{{ env['XMPP_DOMAIN'] or "localhost" }}"
```

**NOTE:** You can see the rest of the example in the [run](https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-ejabberd/blob/master/run) file from the Github repo.

As I understand things the heavy lifting is done by this bit of code:

```
readonly PYTHON_JINJA2="import os;
import sys;
import jinja2;
sys.stdout.write(
    jinja2.Template
        (sys.stdin.read()
    ).render(env=os.environ))
"""
```

And this code is what is used to generate a template file:

```
cat ${CONFIGTEMPLATE} \
      | python -c "${PYTHON_JINJA2}" \
      > ${CONFIGFILE}
```

#### References

- [rroemhild/docker-ejabberd docker image via github](https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-ejabberd)

Comment: This gives me `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'env' is undefined`

Answer (score 2):

In bash let's setup our example

```
export MYENVVAR=foo
```

$ nano example.py

```
from jinja2 import Template
import os
template = Template("Hello {{ env['MYENVVAR'] or 'DefaultVal' }}")
r = template.render(env=os.environ, name='somethingelse')
print(r)
```

Run template

```
    $ python3 example.py
```

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/intro/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/#standard-context) is a list of variables that you can access from your template.
I was trying to access some `app.config` variables and I managed to do it by calling `config`:

```
{% if current_user.id == config['ADMIN_ID'] %}
 ######## SOME HTML ########
{% endif %}
```

Flask-Login adds the `current_user` variable to your templates

Answer (score 0):

My simplest solution for FastAPI

> templates.env.globals.update(getenv=os.getenv)

In Jinja2

> {{ getenv("FOO") }}