# Get or Check Current Environment in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask and Jinja2 but I am abit stuck in checking the current environment the app is running under. On the server, I am simply doing it by:

```
# on the serverside example.py
env = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')
```

I want to achieve the same with Jinja template (in the html) file. The usecase here is to do something based on the environment the app is running under like below

```
# In base.html
{% if env == 'production' %}
   # do something
{% else %}
   # do something else
{% endif %}
```

My challenge is getting the env variable. Any help will be greatly appreciated. This could seem as a duplicate but its completely different. No need to use filters. I am not looking to get an environment variable. That one I am able to achieve via

config['ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_KEY']

What I am trying to do is get the environment itself (local, development, staging or production based on how I have set them in my config)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing OS environment variables from Jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862071/accessing-os-environment-variables-from-jinja2-template)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The link you have provided is about doing it with python, which I have done already.

Comment: This answer in the above question provide a solution for Jinja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27984610/2336650

Comment: It does not. Throws error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'env' is undefined

Answer (score 5):

The config object is available by default in Jinja templates.

Just access it like this:

```
{% if config['ENV'] == 'production' %}
# do something
{% else %}
# do something else
{% endif %}
```

Replace 'ENV' with whatever you have your environment variable named in your config file.