# Is it possible to pass variables to requirements.txt files used by Conda?

Tags: conda, miniconda

I need to install Conda packages from several `requirements.txt` files (as specified in [Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#:%7E:text=Read%20package%20versions%20from%20the%20given%20file.%20Repeated%20file%20specifications%20can%20be%20passed)), and have the versions of the packages be read from environment variables or from another file.

This is an example of how such `requirements.txt` file could look like:

```
# requirements.txt
pandas=$pandas_version
```

So that `export pandas_version=1.4.3` will trigger `$pandas_version` to be replaced by `1.4.3` when running `conda install --file requirements.txt`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I know the docs talk about `requirements.txt` files for whole environment management, but YAMLs definitions have more features and control. They don't solve this particular problem, but I'd still encourage switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be available since version 10: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#using-environment-variables

You can use ENV variables:

```
cat requirements.txt 
locust==${LOCUST_VERSION}

export LOCUST_VERSION="2.20.1";  pip install  -r requirements.txt
```

or you can use dotenv file:

```
cat .env
LOCUST_VERSION="2.20.1"
. ./.env; pip install  -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not directly, no.** Consider using a templating system that would generate files with explicit values using environment variables.

For example, [Jinja can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25862071/570918).